# Java Validation Constraint : How to send validation error to client

Tags: java, rest, validation, constraints

Assume i have the following API :

```
@Path("/api")
public Response api(@Valid @NotNull(message = "In cannot be null") String in) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

When the client sends an Null String the only response he gets its :"Bad Request (400)"

How do I send the Response with the above message ? Or even log the message in my Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue after looking at the below Jersey implantation:

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/bean-validation/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/internal/ValidationExceptionMapper.java

Apparently the *jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server*

property must be set to true (in the web.xml) :

```
 <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
```